# matlab encoding integers to matrix of vectors of 0's and 1's

Tags: matlab, encoding

I have a 1118x1 vector of values from 0 to 10 as such:
5
5
3
4
7
4
1
.
.
I need to encode each value into a 11x1118 Matrix of zeros where the k+1th values is a 1.
For example the first value is a 5 so the 5+1=6 value in the first column with be 1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
 I need to do this for all values up to 1118.
I assume I just need a for loop but am completely lost as to how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `sub2ind`. Try the following code:

```
x = [4;3;1;1;4;7];
y = zeros(11,numel(x));
y(sub2ind(size(y),x+1,(1:numel(x))')) = 1

y =

     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a direct approach using loop:

```
v = [5 5 3 4 7 4 1...]; # your vector
M = zeros(11, length(v)); # the final matrix
for i = 1:length(v)
    e = v(i);
    M(e + 1, i) = 1;
end
```